# Run cmd.exe always as administrator

Tags: privileges, command-line, administrator

I have configured ansicon to display ANSI colors in cmd.exe, but it only works when cmd is run in administrator privileges. I'm also using Launchy to start cmd.exe (not only cmd). Problem is that if I want to run cmd.exe as Administrator I need to use Windows run (Win+R), type cmd and hit SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER.
Do you have any ideas how to optimizie this, to run cmd.exe as Administrator using Launchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download elevate from http://cdn.winability.com/files/Elevate.zip and extract it somewhere.

Configure Launchy to use it like so:

1. Click the little gear icon to open the options dialog.
2. Click the plugins tab.
3. Click "Runner" on the left.
4. Click the + button and enter the following for each field:

   Name - acmd

   Program - **C:\WINDOWS\system32\Elevate.exe**  (OR, *Elevate64.exe* if you are on 64 bit windows)

   Arguments - C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

Like so :

[image]

Now to open an admin cmd prompt just type `acmd` in Launchy.

### Update

I just made a **[screencast](http://youtu.be/ttWO6Iuh8vI)** to demonstrate  the whole process.

#### Acknowledgements

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560366/detect-if-running-with-administrator-privileges-under-windows-xp
2. **[Elevate Documentation](http://www.winability.com/elevate/)**
3. [Original Idea](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/sudo-command-with-launchy?replies=10#post-13902)